Power saving circuit using a touch sensor
I’m designing a touch LED lamp using a 18650 battery and a TTP223 touch sensor (TTP223 datasheet here.  I’m also using a CD4017 to have different light modes and a boost converter to power the LEDs strips.
The issue I’m facing is related to the power consumption when the LEDs are off because of the boost converter. What I want to achieve is a power saving circuit that turns 3.7 V from battery to 0 V by making an open circuit when the lamp is off so that it isn’t always consuming power (like a mechanical switch). Obviously, the sensor will always be powered by the battery. I found some examples of power latching circuits, but I’m not sure if that is the way to go.
PD: I don’t want to use any mechanical relay, or any mechanical part :D

Please ask a specific question where you are stuck with your design.

I wonder if you are thinking of a "low-side FET switch" and a timer/counter auto shutoff?

Why does boost converter need to run when LEDs are off? Some BC ICs have disable lines (and all tend to stop when power is removed :-) ).

I´m using a CD4017 to activate different illumination modes. my ensor output is connected to the counter clk pin, so a different pin is activated after a touch. I have 2 illumination modes, so pin1 - mode1, pin2 - mode2, pin3 - OFF, pin4 - reset,

Did you find a way to do what you wanted? If not your need will be easily met IF we can precisiely understand it.  The words all make sense BUT the overall desire is unclear. || Probably: Circuit idle--> boost converter off. Touch switch touched - boost converter on. 4017 con trolled by touch switches.  || SOUNDS easy enough.

TTP223  output can be active high or lpow. If active low a high side MOSFET can be turned on directly by a key push. If active high you need an extra transistor as an inverter. || BUT if you are toggling a 4017 then any time it is not in idle / off mode you can control the boost converter from that. || Again, sounds ot hard once we are certain of your requirememt.
